# Algorithm for finding the shortest straight line path between two points

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a problem where I have a grid of points, the vertices obstructions and a starting point

I need to determine the shortest, straight line path between the starting point and each point in the grid. Of note, the points are not a graph, so traversal does not need to be graph-like such as with A* or Dijkstra. That is to say, given the following grid:

```
S  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  x  9  10
11 x  13 14
```

Where `S` is the starting point, `E` is the ending point, `x` is an obstruction and any number represents a point (consider it a waypoint), I need to determine the shortest path to reach each numbered point from `S`. For straight lines, this is easy, but to find the points such as `13`, the path can be `S - 9 - 13` and not `S - 5 - 9 - 13`.

The reasoning is that this problem will model flights, which don't necessarily have to abide by traveling a gride in 8 possible directions, and can fly over portions of cells; the points here representing the center of each cell.

I'm not asking for an implementation, just if a well known algorithm for such a problem exists.

My current design is based on finding the initial set of visible points from `S`, then building a subset of the non-visible points. From there, find the furthest point from `S` that is the closest to the set of points that cannot be seen, and repeat.

Comment: [Here's some info that may help in your search for an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any-angle_path_planning).

Comment: You can convert your board to a graph and use the pathfinding algorithms you mentioned.

Comment: @pstatix, if I understand well, you would like to find "change direction" points? Als, are all values in the grid positive?

Comment: There is only one straight line between two given points, so asking the shortest makes little sense. If you constrain the path to be made of grid nodes, then they are usually not aligned.

Comment: @GáborPálovics Using the pathfinding algorithms described does not work, because next nodes are checked in 45' angle increments (moving NSEW + diagonals).  The any-angle algorithms that the prior comment suggested is what I am looking for, will post an answer with an implementation

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting problem, didn't know that can have so practical application. This answer is in Java, because I am most familiar in it, but algorithm is quite simple and comments in the code should help you to reimplement in any language.

I have extended your data grid with one more row, and added `E` (end position). So the complete grid looks like:

```
S  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  x  9  10
11 x  13 14
12 x  E  15
```

Just few remarks:

- Each cell has dimension 1 by 1. It means that each cell has diagonal equal to sqrt(2), because of *d^2 = 1^2 + 1^2*
- Each cell is called `Position(value, row, column)`. `Row` and `Column` values are like coordinates, and `Value` is just a value in the cell. So for example our start is: `new Position("S", 0, 0)` and end is `new Position("E", 4, 2)`
- The proposed algorithm comes after some "shortest path algorithm", like mentioned A* or Dijkstra
- The proposed algorithm looks only at the angles of the shortest path, if values on the shortest path should be considered in computation, then I could replace it with backtracking mechanism.

Algorithm setup:

```java
// shortest path is stored in "positions" list
Position _S = new Position("S", 0, 0);
Position _5 = new Position("5", 1, 1);
...
Position _E = new Position("E", 4, 2);

List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(positions, _S, _5, _9, _13, _E);
```

```java
// obstruction points are stored in "xxx" list
Position x1 = new Position("x", 2, 1);
Position x2 = new Position("x", 3, 1);
Position x3 = new Position("x", 4, 1);

List<Position> xxx = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(xxx, x1, x2, x3);
```

Now the algorithm:

```java
        // iterate from the end
        int index = positions.size()-1;
        while (index > 1) {

            // get three current positions
            Position c = positions.get(index);
            Position b = positions.get(index-1);
            Position a = positions.get(index-2);

            // calculate angle on point "b". Angle is constructed with a-b-c
            int angle = angle(a,b,c);
            if (angle == 0) {                     // angle = 0 means that line is straight
                positions.remove(index-1);        // then just remove the middle one (b)
            } else {                              // in ELSE part check if line goes through any "x" cell
                Line line = new Line(a,c);        
                boolean middleCanBeRejected = true;
                for (Position x : xxx) {
                    if (line.distanceTo(x) < HALF_DIAGONAL) {   // if distance from "x" to "line" is less than sqrt(2), 
                                                                // it means that straight line will pass over "x", 
                                                                // so we are not able to discard the middle point
                        middleCanBeRejected = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (middleCanBeRejected) {          // still in ELSE
                    positions.remove(index-1);      // check result of FOR above
                }
            }
            index--;
        }
```

Finally the test cases:

```
S  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  x  9  10
11 x  13 14
12 x  E  15  

Path:
S    0.0, 0.0
9    2.0, 2.0
E    4.0, 2.0
```

```
S  1  2  3
4  5  6  7
8  22 9  10
11 23 13 14
12 x  E  15 

Path:
S    0.0, 0.0
E    4.0, 2.0
```

Appendix, the utility methods and classes:

```java
    // -1 -> turn right
    // 0  -> straight
    // +1 -> turn left
    // Point2D.ccw() algorithm from Sedgewick's book
    public static int angle(Position a, Position b, Position c) {
        double area = (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y) * (c.x - a.x);
        if (area < 0.0D) { return -1; }
        else { return area > 0.0D ? 1 : 0; }
    }
```

```java
public class Line {

    // A*x + B*y + C = 0
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;

    public Line(Position p1, Position p2) {
        // https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422602/convert-two-points-to-line-eq-ax-by-c-0
        this.A = p1.y - p2.y;
        this.B = p2.x - p1.x;
        this.C = p1.x*p2.y - p2.x*p1.y;
    }

    public double distanceTo(Position p) {
        double nom = Math.abs(A*p.x + B*p.y + C);
        double den = Math.sqrt(A*A + B*B);
        return nom/den;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Position {

    String value;
    double x; // row
    double y; // column

    public Position(String value, double x, double y) {
        this.value = value;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```